# wix disable repair from add remove programs but not from maintenacetypedialog

Tags: wix

I am creating installer in wix.
I want to disable repair from Add Remove Programs, but not from MaintenanceTypDialog.

I have set ARPNOREPAIR to 1. Repair doesn't appear in ARP as expected, but the Repair button is also getting disabled in the Maintenance dialog.

Can anyone please help. I am new to wix.

Answer (score 1):

The Maintenance dialog relies on the ARPNOREPAIR property value as well, that's why when you set this property, the repair option is disabled in both places.

First of all, you should think carefully whether you really want to disable repair in one place, and leave it as is in another one. If that's truly the case, you should modify the Maintenance dialog the way you'd like (for instance, change the condition which disables the Repair button) and inject this modified dialog into the UI sequence.

This might sound pretty scary for beginner, that's why I suggest you starting from the "Customizing Built-in WixUI Dialog Sets" article in WiX.chm file.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can set ARPNOREPAIR in a CA after MaintenanceWelcomeDlg. It seems to work for me. For example,

```
<CustomAction Id="CA_Set_ARPNOREPAIR" Property="ARPNOREPAIR" Value="1" />
<InstallUISequence>
  <Custom Action="CA_Set_ARPNOREPAIR" After='MaintenanceWelcomeDlg' />
</InstallUISequence>
```